# AWS Mutliple CloudFront distributions in S3 Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to add multiple CloudFront distributions to a secured bucket

I saw another StackOverflow post where you add multiple users like this, but I'm getting the Invalid principal in policy error

```
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity **************",
                "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity **************"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
]
```

How can I add multiple principles?

Answer (score 1):

Your policy is correct. However, the error `Invalid principal in policy` often indicates that the principles simply don't exist yet. Make sure that **you've already created** two OAI users and you are using their IDs correctly in your policy.